# Could someone explain why Converting to int and using read line instead of Read fixed my issue?

Tags: c#

So previous I was having a ton of trouble with finding the difference between a randomly generated number and user input. I did a little search and found that I couldn't use `Console.Read();` and that I actually had to use this `int guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` While playing around with it i accidentally made it `Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());` which was in turn making the math completely wrong. Apologies if I'm not explaining myself effectively I'm new to coding and this was meant to be something to learn from. Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play the guessing game?");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (input.Equals("yes"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Alright! The rules are simple, i'll think of a number and you guess it!");
                Console.WriteLine("Alright enter your guess: ");


                int guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


                Random rand = new Random();
                int answer = rand.Next(1,11);

                if (rand.Equals(guess))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations you guessed correctly!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Aww you were so close! I guessed " + answer);
                    int difference = guess - answer;
                    Console.WriteLine("you were only " + Math.Abs(difference) + " away");
                }

            } else

            {
                Console.WriteLine("Closing application...");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Console.Read()
```

Returns you the *ascii* value of a single character being input.

For example, entering 'A' would return `65`. See [here](http://www.asciitable.com/) for a list of ascii codes. Note that the ascii value for `1` is actually `49`.

```
Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Reads the entire line and tries to convert it to an integer.

Comment: Sweet, I didn't even think about the ASCII value. Thankfully I know what you're talking about haha.

Answer (score 0):

Console.Read() will grab just one character and Console.ReadLine() takes the whole line or everything the user types until it found the "Enter" key pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Becuase `Console.Read` reads in characters from the console. It returns, as an integer. So when you enter "yes" the output will be

```
121 = y
101 = e
115 = s
13 =
10 =
```

The final two characters (13 and 10) are equal to the Windows newline.